# Read from file into html listbox by javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, web, listbox

I have been trying to read data from file ans display it into some kind of listBov in html page by using java script.
I have been trying many cources, but there is no working code (I've trying on IE, Firefox and Chrome)

There is one of the attempt to do that, but it also without success:

File 1:
indexTST.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="java.js">
</script>
<body>
<td><form name="listBox" action="javascript:void 0;">
<select name="listBox" size="10">
<option>Select your home location</option>
<option>unknown</option>
</select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    loadData();
   with (document.listBox) {
      listBox.options.length=0;
      for (var i=0; i<Table.length; i++) {
        listBox.options[listBox.options.length]=new Option(Table[i]);
      }
   }
   reset1();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

File 2:
java.js

```
var Table = [];
var txtFile;

function loadData2() {
 Table = [];
 lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
 for (i = 0; i < lines.length-1; i++) {
 Table.push(lines[i]);
 }
}

function loadData() {
var f = "dataFile.txt"; 
alert('01');
txtFile.open("GET", f, false);
alert('02');
txtFile.onreadystatechange=loadData2;
txtFile.send(null);
}
```

File 4:
dataFile.txt

```
Data 01
Data 02
Data 03
end
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Read text data from file (between 1 and 5 000 lines) and the file is on the server side (not local browser side)
2. Display it into some kind of listBox on web page
3. It's need to be "clickable/selectable" - because when user select i.e. item 5 - this one item need to be save into "saved.txt"

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Read a file and appends its contents by line to a list, and log the selected options. I hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Read file</h3>

<input id="file-input" type="file" id="myFile">
<select multiple id="list"></select>
<button onclick="logSelected()">Log selected</button>

<script>
 function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
       var contents = e.target.result;
              console.log(contents);
         var select = document.getElementById('list');
         var lines = contents.split('\n');
         lines.map(function(line){
           var docLine = document.createElement('option');
           docLine.innerHTML = line;
           select.appendChild(docLine);
         });
        }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);

function logSelected(){
var select = document.getElementById("list");
var selected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].selected) selected.push(select.options[i].value);
}
console.log(selected);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for code, but in your case, the file need to be opened by clicking on buton by user and select file on local (browser) side.
But I need to open file without use interaction on server side from server resources and let the user to choose from listBox one item.

Comment: @wcale well, what you in is just an `ajax` request.